# Send part paid cart to PayPal

Tags: forms, paypal, cart

I need to send a cart to PayPal for payment using the FORM integration method where the cart value has already had a part payment made against it, usually by another means, like 'on account' or a gift card for example.

Is there an accepted way to do this?

The only thing I can find is sending the already paid amount as a discount amount but that's not 100% ideal as it isn't in reality a discount.

The other option I came up with was to just send a single line cart with an item of 'Balance of your order XXXX' but this is also not ideal as the customer wouldn't then see the actual items listed when on PayPal.

Many thank.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 PayPal features that you might possibly use to do this:

Authorization and Capture

Authorization & Capture, or Auth/Capture, allows you to authorize the availability of funds for a transaction but delay the capture of funds until a later time. This is often useful for merchants who have a delayed order fulfillment process. Authorize & Capture also enables merchants to modify the original authorization amount due to order changes occurring after the initial order is placed, such as taxes, shipping or gratuity.

Recurring Payments

PayPal Recurring Payments allows you to bill a buyer for a fixed amount of money on a fixed schedule.

Note You can also setup another form of recurring payments using reference transactions to handle payments for varying amounts of money on a varying schedule.

Reference Transactions

A reference transaction is a financial transaction from which subsequent transactions can be derived. For example, a buyer purchases an item on your site, and you use the PayPal transaction ID or reference transaction ID later to initiate another transaction. Reference transactions and billing agreements also enable you to handle recurring payments for varying amounts of money on a varying schedule.

You can read more about these features here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/intro/